# error when calling a function with data set and response variable in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-analysis

I'm trying to call a function which has a data set and response variable in arguments. But I'm getting error.

```
call <- function(data,var){
  mod_3 <- lm(var ~ . , data = data)
  summary(mod_3)
}

call(iris,"Sepal.Length")
```

**Error**

Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ ., data = data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
variable lengths differ (found for 'Sepal.Length')

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the formula with `paste` or `reformulate`

```
call <- function(data,var){
    mod_3 <- lm(as.formula(paste(var, ' ~ .')) , data = data)
    summary(mod_3)
   }
```

-testing

```
call(iris,"Sepal.Length")

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste(var, " ~ .")), data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.79424 -0.21874  0.00899  0.20255  0.73103 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        2.17127    0.27979   7.760 1.43e-12 ***
Sepal.Width        0.49589    0.08607   5.761 4.87e-08 ***
Petal.Length       0.82924    0.06853  12.101  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width       -0.31516    0.15120  -2.084  0.03889 *  
Speciesversicolor -0.72356    0.24017  -3.013  0.00306 ** 
Speciesvirginica  -1.02350    0.33373  -3.067  0.00258 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3068 on 144 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8627 
F-statistic: 188.3 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```